# How to get touch position of screen for any control objective c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

Hi I want to get touch position/point of any control or any where touch happened.

For this I have implemented this but I am not getting correct touch points.

```
   // Create gesture recognizer, notice the selector method
UITapGestureRecognizer *oneFingerTwoTaps =
[[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(oneFingerTwoTaps)] autorelease];
oneFingerTwoTaps.delegate=self;
// Set required taps and number of touches
[oneFingerTwoTaps setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
[oneFingerTwoTaps setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
[[self view] addGestureRecognizer:oneFingerTwoTaps];
```

And

```
 - (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {

    CGPoint point= [touch locationInView:touch.view];
        NSLog(@"Point - %f, %f",point.x,point.y);
    NSLog(@"Touch");
    return NO; // handle the touch
}
```

When I am tried to hit any UIButton, UIImage , UITableView it's not giving me correct point of hit is there any thing I am doing wrong? Please help me. thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code prints the location of the touch in the view that it occured in. So if you touch a 50x100 sized button in the middle, it will print "Point 25.0, 50.0".

If you want to find the touch location of UIScreen, you have to convert the value:

```
 - (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {

    CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
    CGPoint pointOnScreen = [touch.view convertPoint:point toView:nil];
    NSLog(@"Point - %f, %f", pointOnScreen.x, pointOnScreen.y);
    NSLog(@"Touch");
    return NO; // handle the touch
}
```

Or just immediately get the coordinate in the window (screen) space:

```
 - (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {

    CGPoint pointOnScreen = [touch locationInView:nil];
    NSLog(@"Point - %f, %f", pointOnScreen.x, pointOnScreen.y);
    NSLog(@"Touch");
    return NO; // handle the touch
}
```

Comment: Thank you it's working cool for me. I am able to get correct point rest I can do...thanx dude...

Answer (score 0):

This is swift version of @DrummerB's answer.

```
// add as property
var tapRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer! 

// add in viewDidLoad() 
tapRecognizer = UIGestureRecognizer()
tapRecognizer.delegate = self // inherit UIGestureRecognizerDelegate
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)

// listen for delegate method
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
        let pointOnScreen: CGPoint = touch.location(in: nil)
        print("Point - \(pointOnScreen.x), \(pointOnScreen.y)")
        print("Touch")
        return false
}
```

// this worked for me. xcode 9.2, ios 11.2